# java: package org.springframework.stereotype does not exist

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

I'm trying to run a project, so I opened the folder from InteliJ, but it seems that all @Annotations are not working and it gives me this error

> java: package org.springframework.stereotype does not exist

Note:
It's a Gradle project that doesn't have Pom.xml. Not sure if it requires a certain JDK.

build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.1'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'war'
}
```

Comment: We need to see your `dependencies`, you're likely missing a Spring Boot dependency. Depending on your needs, the simplest one could be e.g. `dependencies { implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter' }` with many more possibilities (see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-starters for more Spring Boot Starters). If you have that, maybe just let IntelliJ know you want to refresh by opening the Gradle view and reloading the project from there.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, so it appears that the Gradle settings dependencies were initiated using the key word "compile", When I changed it to "implementation" it the IDE started to re-download all the Gradle files and it eventually worked

Comment: A-ha, yeah. The `compile` thing in dependencies was there in older Gradle versions, that changed in Gradle ... 6 I think? Something like that. Gradle occasionally makes a major release which changes the API, if you want to upgrade you usually need to follow the release notes.